# Centralized/lateral boxes with squared/round edges

Tags: boxes, alignment, rounded-corners

I'm trying to reproduce the boxes below exactly, i.e., a central box with round edges and a lateral box with squared edges.

I've found articles teaching about coloured boxes, with shadows on the back, pictures inside etc. But I just want this simple format, exactly like the ones in the picture.

What's the best solution?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The best solution to reproduce it exactly might be to ask the author what they used. If you want something very, very close you can use `tcolorbox` and tweak it (the manual shows the many options). Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE) showing what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`tcolorbox` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) for the explanation of the parameters.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}% only for testing purpose
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    opacityback=0,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacitybacktitle=0,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    titlerule=0pt,
    titlerule style=white,
    toptitle=4pt,
    bottomtitle=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    left=1mm,
    right=1mm,
    }
\newtcolorbox{mydef}{
    title=Definition,
    grow to left by=2.5mm,% sum of the values: 1mm left margin + 1mm box sep + 0.5mm box rule = 2.5mm
    grow to right by=2.5mm,
    arc=3mm
    }
\newtcolorbox{mymarpar}[1]{
    title={\centering #1},
    sharp corners,
    grow to left by=-2.5mm
    }

\usepackage{mwe}% only for testing purpose

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\blindtext% only for testing purpose
\begin{mydef}
This is my definition. Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
\end{mydef}
Some text blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah

\marginpar{\begin{mymarpar}{The title of my first margin par}
Some text in my first marigin par blah blah blah    
\end{mymarpar}}

Some other text blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah

\marginpar{\begin{mymarpar}{The title of my second margin par}
Some text in my second marigin par blah blah blah 
\end{mymarpar}}

\blindtext % only for testing purpose
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Skillmon suggested in his comment, if you use `\marginnote` you can have better control over vertical placement of the boxes in the margin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{marginnote}
%\usepackage{showframe}% only for testing purpose
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    opacityback=0,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacitybacktitle=0,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    titlerule=0pt,
    titlerule style=white,
    toptitle=4pt,
    bottomtitle=0pt,
    top=2pt,
    left=1mm,
    right=1mm,
    }
\newtcolorbox{mydef}{
    title=Definition,
    grow to left by=2.5mm,% sum of the values: 1mm left margin + 1mm box sep + 0.5mm box rule = 2.5mm
    grow to right by=2.5mm,
    arc=3mm
    }
\newtcolorbox{mymarpar}[1]{
    title={\centering #1},
    sharp corners,
    grow to left by=-2.5mm
    }

\usepackage{mwe}% only for testing purpose

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\blindtext% only for testing purpose
\begin{mydef}
This is my definition. Blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah.
\end{mydef}
Some text blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah

\marginnote{\begin{mymarpar}{The title of my first margin par}
Some text in my first marigin par blah blah blah    
\end{mymarpar}}[-102pt]

Some other text blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah, blah

\marginnote{\begin{mymarpar}{The title of my second margin par}
Some text in my second marigin par blah blah blah 
\end{mymarpar}}[14pt]

\blindtext % only for testing purpose
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For better control over vertical placement of the boxes in the margin one might be interested in using `marginnote` for the placement.

Comment: That wasn't meant as a suggested correction, just as an additional option for perfectionists. Your answer looks great as is.